# javascript to flash communication without embedding

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, callback, window, externalinterface

I am calling my Main.swf from localhost Xampp which contains a prompt button upon click of that button promptclick function is called

**AS3 code**

```
function promptClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var desiredURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:NewWindow=window.open('save.html','newWin','width=600,height=400,left =0,top=0,toolbar=No,location=No,scrollbars=No,status=No,resizable=No,fullscreen=No'); NewWindow.focus(); void(0);");

navigateToURL(desiredURL, "_self");

}
```

this window (newwin) has a button "Accept" defined in "save.html" , upon click of Accept button the data should be send to calling Main.swf.
I am not able to make a call from javascript window to my Main.swf function
through externalInterface callback in AS3

I have found that when i embed Main.swf on the same window which contains my editor it works(externalInterface call to Actionscript), but i don't want to embed swf on editor page
Is there any way i can make call to from javascript window to swf directly without embedding?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you have 2 windows, one has a swf, the other has a javascript function. You'd like to call the javascript function from the swf?

Comment: Yes i want to call javascript function from swf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be calling a javascript function which is defined outside.  Example:

**Javascript file:**

```
var formWin,

formWinParams = {
    btnSelector: '.btn-on-form-win',
    name: 'windowNameHere',
    src: 'save.html',

    // Advanced string join (param could just be one long string instead)
    params: [
    'width=600',
    'height=400',
    'left=0',
    'top=0',
    'toolbar=No',
    'location=No',
    'scrollbars=No',
    'status=No',
    'resizable=No',
    'fullscreen=No'
    ].join(',')
},

swfFile;

/**
 * Gets a javascript object reference to a swf file
 * @return object
 * @note You should swfobject or jquery to get your swf file but 
 * you might also need to setup a mechanism to make sure swf file 
 * is ready for interaction (or swf load is complete)
 * @see example of load check http://abi.edu/js/new-video-gallery.js
 */
function getSwf (movieName) {
    if ( navigator.appName.indexOf( "Microsoft" ) != -1 ){
        return window[ movieName ];
    }
    else {
        return document[ movieName ];
    }
}

function onBtnClick (e) {
    swfFile.functionFromSwfFileHere();
}

/**
 * Gets form window lazily (if not there create it)
 * @return window object
 * @note Javascript function params are optional so we use the || operator to check if 
 * params are set otherwise we use our own values.
 */
function getFormWindow (src, name, params) {
    src = src || formWinParams.src;
    name = name || formWinParams.name;
    params = params || formWinParams.params;

    // Create window if not already created
    if (formWin === null) {
        formWin = window.open(src, name, params);
        // Setup handling of the form window button click
        $(formWinParams.btnSelector, formWin).click(onBtnClick);
    }

    // Bring window to front
    formWin.focus();

    return formWin;
}

// Wrap initialization of script for ease of use
function init () {    
    // Get reference to swf file
    swfFile = getSwf('swfFileIdHere');

    // Or use a library like jquery
    swfFile = $('#swf-file-id-here');
}

// Initialize javascript on window load (using jquery)
$(function () {
    init();
});
```

Now change UrlRequest source to something like

`"javascript: getFormWindow();"`

or

`"javascript: getFormWindow('save.html', 'saveWin');"`

and it is all handled from there simplifying your actionscript and javascript code and making it more dynamic.

Comment: I did that but in place of URLRequest i used externalInterface.call in Actionscript, it works
but now i have a problem in externalInterface callBack 
_______________________________________________
In my formWin:-
I can alert the id, name & other property of swf  via 
window.opener.parent.document.getElementById('externalInterface').receiveTextFromJS("dummy text");
_______________________________________________
AS3 code:-
ExternalInterface.addCallback("receiveTextFromJS",receivedTextAtAS);
function receivedTextAtAS(val:String)
{
 promptText.text=val;
}

Comment: Also, when i debug in Firefox using firebug I have found the error
TypeError: receiveTextFromJS is not a function
What's that problem?

Comment: I've never tried to send image data to flash before.  If you need image data in flash you should create a class that leverages Flash's loader clases for loading external images.  I created some classes a long time ago but don't quite remember since I barely code in actionscript any more.  For the class think something like ExternalData which might be able to load text files as well as image files.

Comment: Once loaded its content loader info data could be converted into an image, bitmap or movieclip (if memory serves me well).  Check the actionscript docs on more info on how to get it done (@see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was calling swf object before it was loaded
Here is my working callback code:-

```
function onFlashReady() {
        sendToAS("value");
    }

    function callJS(value) {
        onFlashReady();
        return "Hi Flash.";
    }

    function thisMovie(movieName) {
         if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
             return window[movieName];
         } else {
             return document[movieName];
         }
     }
     function sendToAS(value) 
     {  
         thisMovie("externalInterface").callAS(value);
     }
```

Although i am sending string data but if i try to send image data as object to flash my browser hangs
I need to send image data to flash.
What should i do in order to send the data?